# How to exclude a file only for selected dependencies

Tags: maven, jar

Is there a way to achieve the following in Maven? I want to exclude a file (see `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter` below) from the final jar file built by Maven.

```
drools-camel-5.3.0.Final.jar
+-- META-INF
  +-- services 
    +-- org
      +-- apache
        +-- camel 
          +-- component
            +-- TypeConverter
```

I can use something like the following:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/TypeConverter</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

However, in doing so the `TypeConverter` file will be excluded from all the jars (including the two examples I've shown below). I don't want that. `TypeConverter` should only be excluded from selected jars (in this case `drools-camel-5.3.0.Final.jar` only).

Is this possible in Maven ? If yes, how ?  I currently have only one pom.xml file with all my dependencies and plugins.

```
camel-http-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
+-- META-INF
  +-- services 
    +-- org
      +-- apache
        +-- camel 
          +-- component
            +-- TypeConverter

camel-twitter-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
+-- META-INF
  +-- services 
    +-- org
      +-- apache
        +-- camel 
          +-- component
            +-- TypeConverter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with Maven [shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), take a look at [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) for details.